# Excel COUNTIF for comma separated values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following range of values:

```
National museum of Natural History
Archaeological Museum, Art Museum, Agricultural Museum, Marine Museum
National museum of Natural History, Art Museum
National museum of Natural History, Archaeological Museum, Science Museum
Open-air Museum, Art Museum
```

This means there can be more than one value in one column, separated by commas.

I want to count each value, for example: all "Archaeological Museum" in this range. I have used the COUNTIF method but it seems not to be enough:

```
COUNTIF(A1:A6, "Archaeological Museum")
```

=> result: `0`

=> expected result: `2`

Is there an only way to spilt the column based on comma or is there any other ways without creating a new column?

Comment: `COUNTIF(A1:A6, "*Archaeological Museum*")`

Comment: oh thanks it has been a while since i use excel, I'm so dumb

Answer (score 1):

This is not a dumb question. This one has been asked and answer many time prior.

I would do it like [show on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210897/excel-how-to-split-cells-by-comma-delimiter-into-new-cells/72211471#72211471)